# Can't Run or Test My NodeJS script

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm a Beginner at NodeJS & I've Written This script and saved it as server.js, Now I'm Using localhost (WAMP) to test the script, but when i open the WAMP and open The Folder Where the script is located, and click on "server.js" only the script appear

I Can't Run My Script, So is there another programs used to run NodeJS scripts or I'm Not Understanding or not ?

That is ma code, any help ?

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    response.write('hello world');
    response.end();
});

server.listen(8001);
```

Comment: WAMP has nothing to do with Node.js. Installing [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/) would be a start.

Comment: I've Installed It but, after installation it opened a black screen as command prompt, but i don't what to write ... is there a tutorial to this program how to use it ?

Comment: this is what i've written, this is the output 

http://imgur.com/FrQOT9J

Comment: Open a command prompt, cd to where your server.js is located then type: node server.js

Comment: Ok i've done this but it seems that it go in infinite loop ... is there something wrong with the code, or any extra programs to install ?? http://i.imgur.com/FOW6quc.jpg

Comment: Why do you think it is in an infinite loop? After you type node server.js in a command prompt, leave the command prompt open, open a new browser window and navigate to localhost:8001. What do you see?

Comment: fine, every thing is ok, but something is not clear i ordered the console to write 'hello world' once but it write it twice, can u explain why "is it ordinary ?" http://i.imgur.com/aISJqpg.jpg

Comment: Your browser probably made a request for the favicon, which is why you see 2 log lines. You could inspect the request object to get more information about what is going on.

Comment: Now i've added io.socket and this msg appear
this is code ==> http://codepad.org/0pdtDp3V
msg ==> http://i.imgur.com/fK6iO8H.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really take a look at http://www.nodebeginner.org to get started. From that website it says:

Let's start with the server module. Create the file server.js in the root directory of your project, and fill it with the following code:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

That's it! You just wrote a working HTTP server. Let's prove it by running and testing it. First, execute your script with Node.js:

```
node server.js
```

Now, open your browser and point it at `http://localhost:8888/`. This should display a web page that says "Hello World".

Comment: Now i've added io.socket and this msg appear this is code ==> codepad.org/0pdtDp3V msg ==> i.imgur.com/fK6iO8H.jpg

Comment: can you post the code you wrote that produces this error? It looks like you wrote var io.listen(server); when you should have wrote:
var aVariableName = io.listen(server);

Comment: Perhaps you don't have nodejs or socket.io properly installed. Your code has no errors and worked fine on my computer. I pasted the code into a file test.js. Then in that same directory i ran "npm install socket.io" after that I ran "node test.js" and opened up a browser and typed in "http://localhost:8080" Everything worked fine.

Comment: The Problem is that it's always giving me 404 ... it's not going to the html page

Answer (score 0):

Do not run "node" as its own command - in the image you are in the REPL (which is for typing and executing code line-by-line)

open the directory where the code is, shift-right-click and open a command prompt, then type node server.js (the .js is not required). It is possible you don't have node in your path... in which case I would start over and consult a tutorial like [this](http://dailyjs.com/2012/05/03/windows-and-node-1/) . you will know this is the problem because when you type node in the command prompt you will get a command not found error.

Also, forget using WAMP, just open a browser and type localhost:8001/ in the urlbar to access the node server.

Good luck.